# What ifluences whether a formula of a predicate logic is true/false in some particular interpretation of a language L?

Tags: logic

It is not clear to me, what influences whether a formula in a predicate logic is true/false in some particular interpretation of the language L. In propositional logic we valuate every atomic formula as being 1 or 0 (in other words, we decide whether it is true/false). However in predicate logic, it seems to me that whether a statement is true/false in some particular interpretation is based on some kind of common sense. It it really that vague?

Would you please clarify that for me?

Comment: No, it is not based on "common sense". [Interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic)#Interpretations_of_a_first-order_language) maps language symbols to a set with relations, and truth values of formulas are then evaluated according to prescribed rules. The procedure is more complex than in propositional logic because the set can be infinite.

Comment: We have symbols and we interpret them in a "context"; different context-different meaning (and truth values). This is the "gist" of semantic for predicate logic.

Comment: Silly example: "for all x, Px". Is it true or false ? It depends on the context... If the domain is the set **N** of natural numbers, and if we read the symbol P as meaning "it is Prime", then the interpreted formula will we FALSE: it is not true that every natural number is Prime.

Comment: If instead, we consider the domain **H** of human beings and interpret the symbol P as meaning "it is Mortal", then the interpreted formula will be TRUE: it is true that every human is Mortal.

Comment: Your example with prime numbers and humans is exactly what cause me problem to understand. Where it is written that human beings are mortal? It would seem natural to me to write it instead more explicitly, for example: "H = {a, b, c, d} is a domain of Human beings a, b, c, d and we interpret the symbol P as meaning "being mortal". Further we explicitly say for which elements of the domain H is P true: P is true in this 
particular interpretation for elements P = {a, b}." This definition is common in some textbooks. But when it comes to numbers I haven't seen to use this "method".

Comment: Therefore for example P(a) is true and P(c) is false.

Comment: Of course the example with human beings is absurd but sometimes a person doesn't have this common sense to distinguish whether the formula is true in some interpretation. The example with prime numbers could be the case for someone. Imagine a person who doesn't know anything about prime numbers and not even numbers. Such a person wouldn't be able to distinguish, under which predicate interpretation and for what numbers we call the formula to be true.

Comment: As said in my comment above: "silly example... But nothing change with your proposed one. The general "mechanism" of interpretation of a FOL formula works the same way with interpretations based on *finite* domains whose elements are listed. As per Conifold's comments above, it seems that you are missing the possibility of *infinite* domains, and this is exactly what made the success of modern mathematical logic: the possibility of applying predicate logic to mathematical theories.

Comment: "Imagine a person who doesn't know anything about prime numbers. Such a person wouldn't be able to distinguish, under which predicate interpretation we call the formula to be true." But the point is that a formula is not TRUE "per se": it is true in some interpretations and false in others. If a person do not know numbers, he will not interpret Px as a statement about numbers.

Comment: "But the point is that a formula is not TRUE "per se": it is true in some interpretations and false in others." - yes, I'm aware of that very well. "If a person do not know numbers, he will not interpret Px as a statement about numbers" - not sure if I understand your point here. Let's give example: Interpretation M with universe K ={1,2,3,4} and predicate symbol P interpreted as - "x is even". Now let's consider formula (∀x)P(x). Since I know how even numbers are defined and what numbers are, I know that this formula is false under this interpretation M.

Comment: The point is: how a person without a prior knowledge of math can also know the formula is false in this interpretation?

Comment: A person without prior knowledge of math would not know how to evaluate compound formulas in propositional logic even if they knew truth values of atomic ones either. Evaluation of ∀xP(x) involves a similar skill, but over an infinite set of atomic formulas. For complex P no human may ever be able to complete the task, but that is beside the point. The point of interpretation is to prescribe a value platonistically, not make it computable by humans, especially without knowledge of math.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I uh... think your string of comments is enough to warrant an answer. ;)